# Remove invalid characters from soap response in JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am trying to get the lists present on a sharepoint site using SP webservice.

```
Lists listsSevice = new Lists(new URL(spSiteURL + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl"));
listsSevice.setHandlerResolver(new SPHandlerResolver());
spListsServiceIfx = listsSevice.getListsSoap();
// Calling the List Web Service
GetListItemsResponse.GetListItemsResult result = spListsServiceIfx .getListItems(listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, webID);
```

However, I get this error because of some invalid character present in soap response.

```
com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.soap.DeserializationException: Failed to read a response: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal character entity: expansion character (code 0x15 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1125,122]]
```

I tried to modify the SOAPMessage to remove invalid characters from response.

```
public class SOAPMessageHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
    System.out.println("in handleMessage");
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    System.out.println("outboundProperty: " + outboundProperty);

    try {
        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            System.out.println(" SOAP Request ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" SOAP Response ");
            SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
            message.writeTo(System.out);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            message.writeTo(out);
            String messageAsString = new String(out.toByteArray());
            /*smc.setMessage(new SOAPMessage( 
            stripNonValidXMLCharacters(message.getSOAPPart().toString())));*/
        }

    } catch (SOAPException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("in soap msg handler..." + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(""); 

    return true;
}
```

But I get an exception at

```
 SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
```

The stack trace is:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1125; columnNumber: 122; Illegal character entity: expansion character (code 0x15
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1125,122]
at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.SOAPMessageContextImpl.getMessage(SOAPMessageContextImpl.java:86)
at com.cah.ecm.sharepoint.migrator.util.SOAPMessageHandler.handleMessage(SOAPMessageHandler.java:25)
at com.cah.ecm.sharepoint.migrator.util.SOAPMessageHandler.handleMessage(SOAPMessageHandler.java:1)
at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandleMessageReverse(HandlerProcessor.java:341)
at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandlersResponse(HandlerProcessor.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientSOAPHandlerTube.callHandlersOnResponse(ClientSOAPHandlerTube.java:163)
at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerTube.processResponse(HandlerTube.java:164)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:651)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:323)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:161)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:113)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:144)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getListItems(Unknown Source)
at com.cah.ecm.sharepoint.migrator.sharepoint.client.SharepointClient.getListItemNodes(SharepointClient.java:292)
at com.cah.ecm.sharepoint.migrator.sharepoint.client.SharepointClient.getListItems(SharepointClient.java:389)
at com.cah.ecm.sp.jde.main.TestIterateAllSPFiles.main(TestIterateAllSPFiles.java:35)
```

Please help me with where I am wrong and if there is an alternate way to remove invalid characters from SOAP response.

Thanks!

Comment: A better course of action would be to fix the service provider, so that it complies with the XML/SOAP spec. Are you able to invoke the service in soapUI?

Comment: Yes, I am able to invoke the service in SoapUI. The XML response contains this character &#21; which causes the code to trip.

Comment: &#21 (U+0015) is an invalid character in XML 1.0. See [Valid characters in XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML).

Comment: I am trying to handle this in my code and remove/replace invalid characters in the xml response

Answer (score 0):

One option is to implement your own `SAAJMetaFactory` that will create custom `MessageFactory`. Like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

import com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl;

public class OwnSAAJMetaFactoryImpl extends SAAJMetaFactoryImpl {
    @Override
    protected MessageFactory newMessageFactory(String protocol) throws SOAPException {
        final MessageFactory f = super.newMessageFactory(protocol);
        return new MessageFactory() {

            @Override
            public SOAPMessage createMessage(MimeHeaders headers, InputStream in) throws IOException, SOAPException {
                in = doCleaingStuff(in);
                return createMessage(headers, in);
            }

            @Override
            public SOAPMessage createMessage() throws SOAPException {
                return f.createMessage();
            }
        };
    }

    private InputStream doCleaingStuff(InputStream in) {
        // TODO implement it
        return null;
    }
}
```

According to [SAAJMetaFactory#getInstance()](https://saaj.java.net/nonav/spec-1.3/api/javax/xml/soap/SAAJMetaFactory.html#getInstance()) documentation your OwnSAAJMetaFactoryImpl can be exposed through system property

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory", "own.package.OwnSAAJMetaFactoryImpl");
```

or any of this way

> - Use the javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory system property.
> - Use the properties file "lib/jaxm.properties" in the JRE directory. This configuration file is in standard java.util.Properties format and
>     contains the fully qualified name of the implementation class with the
>     key being the system property defined above.
> - Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification), if available, to determine the classname. The Services API will look for
>     a classname in the file META-INF/services/javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory
>     in jars available to the runtime.
> - Default to com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.